# $ ignored when trying to execute query

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

I use the following Oracle command to find out the Oracle database logging mode:

```
select name,log_mode from v$database
```

That command is running without any problem from the an interactive session:

```
SQL> select name,log_mode from v$database;

NAME      LOG_MODE
--------- ------------
T2       NOARCHIVELOG
```

But failed to run properly when running from Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1;export ORACLE_SID=T2;/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus -L -s "user/password" <<EOF
select name,log_mode from v$database;
quit
EOF
```

With the following error message:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

When checking the `stdout` I can see that the rest of the command after the `$` sign is ignored:

```
StdOut = select name,log_mode from v
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I've tried multiple ways to handle the problematic `$` sign using: `""`, `''`, `"\`, But none of them help so far. my latest try is as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1;export ORACLE_SID=T2;/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus -L -s "user/password" <<EOF
select name,log_mode from v'$'database;
quit
EOF
```

But now the Stdout is with the ' single quotes:

```
    StdOut = select name,log_mode from v'$'database
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Is worth to mention, that the account I'm using has both `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege and the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF` to avoid shell substitution in the input data ("here-document"), see
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument or
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=T2
/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus -L -s "user/password" <<'EOF'
select name,log_mode from v$database;
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` is being interpreted by your shell before Oracle sees it; she shell is substituting the `$database`, which isn't defined. This is nothing to do with Oracle - it's just how shells work.

You need to escape the `$` sign, as you've realised; you said you tried `\$`, but that is what you need:

```
select name,log_mode from v\$database;
```

So:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1;export ORACLE_SID=T2;/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus -L -s "user/password" <<EOF
select name,log_mode from v\$database;
quit
EOF
```

which works.

Comment: as i wrote, i tried with \$. and still getting the same error. `ReturnCode = 0
    StdOut = select name,log_mode from v
                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



    StdErr = /usr/bin/ksh: ^M:  not found
`

Comment: What are you using to run this - it doesn't look like you're just executing your shell script on the command line, from the `ReturnCode` etc. labels; and not sure where the `ksh` reference is coming from. If you have another level of shell doing something, perhaps escaping twice (`v\\$database`) might help, but without seeing what the intermediate layer is doing it's hard to tell. Please add that into to the question, along with your operating system, and the `sh` and `ksh` versions involved.